# Views are gone when ConstraintSet.applyTo

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to extend the ConstraintLayout functionality to have a ProgressBar with fullscreen translucent background color. The idea is that I could reuse this layout and call `hideLoading()` and `showLoading()`. Progress bar has to be centered.

**Problem is**: when `constraintSet.applyTo(this)` is called all views that had `ConstraintSet.connect(...)` on them are GONE, or not drawn. As all operations on them are ignored and they are not displayed on the screen at all.

Here is what I have :

```
public class ConstraintLayout extends android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout {

    private View background;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    public ConstraintLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        addLoader();
    }

    public ConstraintLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        addLoader();
    }

    public ConstraintLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        addLoader();
    }

    private void addLoader(){
        int wrapContent = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        int matchParent = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
        constraintSet.clone(this);

        background = new View(getContext());
        background.setBackgroundColor(getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.background_loader_color));
        background.setId(generateViewId());
        addView(background, new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(matchParent, matchParent));

        constraintSet.connect(background.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 
                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
        constraintSet.connect(background.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 
                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
        constraintSet.connect(background.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, 
                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);
        constraintSet.connect(background.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 
                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);

        progressBar = new ProgressBar(getContext(), null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
        progressBar.setId(generateViewId());
        addView(progressBar, new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(wrapContent, wrapContent));

        constraintSet.connect(progressBar.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 
                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
        constraintSet.connect(progressBar.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 
                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
        constraintSet.connect(progressBar.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, 
                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, 0);
        constraintSet.connect(progressBar.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, 
                ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END, 0);

        constraintSet.applyTo(this);
    }

    public void showLoading(){
        background.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    }

    public void hideLoading(){
        background.setVisibility(GONE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
    }
}
```

Here is what I have
[image: img]
and what I want
[image: what i want]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you’re setting your Background constraints as `MATCH_PARENT` which is invalid in ConstraintLayouts. I assume you meant `LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT`.

I assume you want your layout to “simulate” this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bkg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Which looks like:

[image]

`tl;dr`: Change the line `int matchParent = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;` to `int matchParent = LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT;`

**UPDATE**: I tried my own solution and didn’t work, so I spend a few minutes looking at your code and found the problem. I am using ConstraintLayout 1.1.0

1. Yes, use MATCH CONSTRAINT.
2. You are setting constraints for views that don’t *yet* exist… so I recreated your “custom layout” and here’s mine:

Main Activity just inflates this via `setContentView(R.layout.demo_layout)`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                             xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                             xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                             android:id="@+id/root"
                                             android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                             android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                             tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >
    <com.so.ProgressConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/demo_progress_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And my `ProgressConstraintLayout`… which I copied from yours and modified:

```
package com.so;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
import android.support.constraint.ConstraintSet;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

public class ProgressConstraintLayout extends ConstraintLayout {

    private View background;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    public ProgressConstraintLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        addLoader();
    }

    public ProgressConstraintLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        addLoader();
    }

    public ProgressConstraintLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        addLoader();
    }

    private void addLoader() {
        int wrapContent = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        int matchConstraint = LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT;

        ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();

        background = new View(getContext());
        background.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright, getContext().getTheme()));
        background.setId(generateViewId());
        addView(background, new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(matchConstraint, matchConstraint));

        progressBar = new ProgressBar(getContext(), null, android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressBar.setId(generateViewId());
        addView(progressBar, new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(wrapContent, wrapContent));

        constraintSet.clone(this);
        constraintSet.connect(background.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP);
        constraintSet.connect(background.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
        constraintSet.connect(background.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START);
        constraintSet.connect(background.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END);
        constraintSet.connect(progressBar.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP);
        constraintSet.connect(progressBar.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
        constraintSet.connect(progressBar.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START);
        constraintSet.connect(progressBar.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END);
        constraintSet.applyTo(this);
    }

    public void showLoading() {
        background.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    }

    public void hideLoading() {
        background.setVisibility(GONE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
    }
}
```

And if you’re wondering how it looks… pretty boring but who am I to judge:
[image]

Comment: You are right about what you say about "match_parent". Can you get the code to work (not XML) with the current production version of `ConstraintLayout` (1.1.0) as the OP intends? I am curious.

Comment: I’d have to try, but I can’t “now”. I was going to but then looked at the time. I’ll try later today and report back (or maybe tomorrow) :)

Comment: Sounds good. It's not a challenge - just want to make sure I'm not sending the OP down a garden path. Make sure you try with version 1.1.0.

Comment: @Cheticamp ^ there, it works but I had to modify it a little bit ;)

Comment: Interesting! I'll have to take a closer look. I wonder if it has something to do with LEFT->START and RIGHT->END?

Comment: No, it has to do with the order of how the layout is constructed. OP was adding constraints and then the views, I add the views, then clone the constraint set, then add the _new_ constraints, then apply it.

Comment: That must be it - add then clone.

Comment: Although this solved the OP's problem, I still think there is an underlying issue or, maybe, things have just changed. The original approach falls under manual creation as defined [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet) and should work.

Comment: Maybe we can get someone from Google to confirm it for us…

Comment: Interesting, I asked anyway, perhaps we can get an official response as to _why_ the set needs those constraints (and didn’t before).

Comment: Unless this is you, I think the problem has already been submitted to the tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79313155

Comment: @Cheticamp not me, so … it’s a matter of waiting now. ;) I’ll hope it gets :eyed: by Google, but unlikely to be this week anyway (I/O 2018 starts tomorrow) and everybody must be in-flames @ Mountain View.

Answer (score 2):

There has been a change since 1.1.0-beta5 that now requires code to explicitly set the width and height of views to manually defined a `ConstraintLayout` and its `ConstraintSet`. I am not sure exactly the reason, but the code goes as follows:

*After connecting `background` add*

```
    constraintSet.constrainWidth(background.getId(),matchParent);
    constraintSet.constrainHeight(background.getId(),matchParent);
```

*After connecting `progressBar` add*

```
    constraintSet.constrainWidth(progressBar.getId(),wrapContent);
    constraintSet.constrainHeight(progressBar.getId(),wrapContent);
```

Without this code, the width and height of the views are not set within the constraints. This code makes sure the width and height are set.

See the documentation for constraining [width](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet.html#constrainWidth(int,%20int)) and [height](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintSet#constrainHeight(int,%20int)).